# html form text elements, not be parsed correctly into javascript method

Tags: javascript

I have a simple calculate.js function, that calculates a price and displays it to the user. Here is my function:

```js
function calculatePrice() {

  //Get selected data  
  var width = document.getElementById("width");  

  var heigth = document.getElementById("height");   

  var elt = document.getElementById("style");
  var style = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;

  elt = document.getElementById("materials");
  var materials = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;

  elt = document.getElementById("priority");
  priority= elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;

  //convert data to integers
  style = parseInt(style);
  materials = parseInt(materials);
  priority = parseInt(priority);
  width = parseInt(width);
  height = parseInt(height);   

  //calculate total value  
  var total = 500* (height + width) + (style + materials + priority)

  //print value to  PicExtPrice 
  document.getElementById("PicExtPrice").value=total;
 }
```

Everything was working fine until I started using the width and height variables. The issue is that they are text fields, and I want the user to 
input a number directly, instead of selecting an option like the other values.

HTML code for input fields:

```html
<div class="col-lg-6">
  Indæst bredden på ønskede malleri 
  <input name="width" type="text" maxlength="512"  id="width" onChange="calculatePrice()"/> 
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6">
  Indæst længden på ønskede malleri 
  <input name="heigth" type="text" maxlength="512"  id="heigth" onChange="calculatePrice()"/> 
</div>
```

example of an dropdown option:

```html
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <SELECT NAME="Stil" onChange="calculatePrice()" id="style">
    <OPTION value="0">Hvilken stil skal malleriet være mallet i</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="1">Kubisme</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="2">Impressionisme</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="3">Pop/Ekspressionisme</OPTION>
  </SELECT>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello bailey. you should set type of your weight and height inputs to numbers type="number" . in this way user can only type number in it and in javascript you should parseInt(x) the value you get from that element.

Comment: i have tried this, but it did not help

Comment: You had forgotten a semicolon to terminate the line that performs the computation. Expect JavaScript to hiccup in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some incorrect spelling on your inputs Id and in javascript, please check and correct them.

Change your javascript function to this and your problem is should be solved.

```
function calculatePrice() {

        //Get selected data  
        var width = document.getElementById("width").value;

        var height = document.getElementById("height").value;

        var elt = document.getElementById("style");
        var style = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;

        elt = document.getElementById("materials");
        var materials = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;

        elt = document.getElementById("priority");
        priority = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;

        //convert data to integers
        style = parseInt(style);
        materials = parseInt(materials);
        priority = parseInt(priority);
        width_int = width == "" ? 0 : parseInt(width);
        height_int = height == "" ? 0 : parseInt(height);

        //calculate total value  
        var total = 500 * (width_int + height_int) + (style + materials + priority);

        //print value to  PicExtPrice 
        document.getElementById("PicExtPrice").value = total;

    }
```

The problem was you should first get value of element. second you should check it if there is no value set it to zero.

Comment: I agree with this answer but you're missing a semicolon at the end of this line (not sure if it would make a difference but maybe good to correct it) var total = 500 * (width_int + height_int) + (style + materials + priority);

Comment: thanks Sarah. I did correct it but it doesnt make problem when I tested it.

Comment: @MasmoudAmidi That's because javascript autofills semi-colons to prevent unnecessary errors. However it still is a good practice to use them nonetheless

Comment: @rawrplus Ok that's good. I was just following good practice :) I tested this answer too and it works :)

Comment: Perhaps a good thing to note, this would throw an error if you used strict mode via `"use strict";` or even used any common module programming model.

Comment: @Masoud Amidi: You can simplify checking the values even further by unconditionally converting the string to an integer and subsequently test the result whether or not it is a NaN (in that case you simply reset the value to 0).

Comment: @Robidu : Yes. that is a nice way to do it too. I just test it and its works. Thanks man.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem correctly, you are parsing the input object instead of the value of the input.

You can take any value from an object that was retrieved with `getElementById` using the value getter.

```
var height = document.getElementById("heigth");
height = parseInt(height.value); //instead of height = parseInt(height); parse the value, not the object
```

Use it on both height and width and you will work with the values that the user has provided.

Answer (score 0):

in the var height line you have a typo. You have typed heigth.

Comment: i have fixed this now

Comment: in input's name also you have the same spelling!. And You haven't corrected. HEIGHT.. make corrections in all places

Comment: @baileyhaldwin You also have id="heigth" instead of id="height" in the HTML <input> element

Comment: whatever spelling you use, make it same everywhere.

Comment: @Sarah, i have fixed this now, but the problem still occurs

Comment: @baileyhaldwin Also Oscar is right in what he said below. you need to get the value of the input field (not just the input field itself) so something like var height = document.getElementById("height").value; (note the .value on the end).

Comment: it should be var width=document.getElementById("width").value; same thing for height. You omitted .value ( We didn't notice as we were carried away with the typos!) Add .value. at both places, it shoud work

Answer (score 0):

I have derived a test case from your descriptions, and after a bit of tinkering I got it to work as it should (it actually computes a result from the input). However, I have reworked things a bit.

Keyword "Unobtrusive JavaScript": I'm not hard-coding any event handlers into the (X)HTML, but instead I'm waiting for the **DOMContentLoaded** event to fire and use it to attach event listeners to each individual input field (this way I am guaranteed to have the entire DOM tree set up).

Furthermore I have trapped all values by attempting to convert everything to integers and subsequently also check for the values being a NaN - in the latter case your calculation would produce an invalid result and cause your JavaScript to abort. However, when NaNs are trapped and reset to zeroes, the computation works just fine.

As a last hint, please scan your code and check for any typos - misspelled IDs and the likes that could cause `getElementById` to return null or undefined.

As a final measure you can also unclutter your code by avoiding indexing into the selections, but instead retrieve their values directly (yes, `document.getElementById('style').value` works!). I successfully checked that in my test case.